# Doesn't work - Cross-domain Redirect in google form in an iframe in google sheets app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I have a function `launchForm` within a Google Sheet which calls another function `createForm` with a single question. I get the URL of the newly created form and pass it into a sandbox `Iframe` using `UrlFetchApp`, as shown below:

```
function launchForm() {

var form = createForm(); // separate function that works fine

formUrl = form.getPublishedUrl()
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(formUrl,{"followRedirects" : true}); // true if automatic redirecting works
var formHtml = response.getContentText();

var htmlApp = HtmlService
      .createHtmlOutput(formHtml)
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
      .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL) // did this to prevent error but didn't help

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

ss.show(htmlApp);
}
```

I have created a custom menu in sheets to run the `launchForm` function.

The trouble is, that the new form URL is at `docs.google.com/a/`, while the sheet is at `docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/...`

This means that the `iframe`, instead of loading the form, opens up to a sign-in screen in when I (the creator of the form) tries to run it. When someone else with edit permissions runs the script, he sees the form as expected, but is then unable to make any inputs into the form.

I have read about CORS, X-frame-options, OAuth2, and nothing seems to provide the precise answer about what I must do. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide your error logs?

Comment: Not sure how to provide an error log. In cases when I see the google sign-in screen, there's no error generated. When I don't see the google sign-in screen (i.e., a google account other than creator of the script with edit permissions on the Sheet), I get a bunch of 'code' XMLHttpRequest cannot load 'code' errors, where the description says "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin is therefore not allowed access